# Postgres Aggregations

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, gaps-and-islands

i have a postgres table as below

| Username | Event | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UserA | Log in | 02/03/2020 07:06:30 |
| UserA | Log in | 02/03/2020 10:15:15 |
| UserA | Log in | 02/03/2020 10:17:01 |
| UserA | Log Out | 02/03/2020 10:28:55 |
| UserA | Log in | 02/07/2019 14:56:15 |
| UserA | Log in | 02/08/2019 10:50:34 |
| UserA | Log Out | 02/08/2019 10:57:21 |

The resulting table in trying to achieve is as follows:

| Username | log_in_Event | log_in_Date | log_out_event | log_out_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UserA | Log in | 02/03/2020 07:06:30 | null | null |
| UserA | Log in | 02/03/2020 10:15:15 | null | null |
| UserA | Log in | 02/03/2020 10:17:01 | Log Out | 02/03/2020 10:28:55 |
| UserA | Log in | 02/07/2019 14:56:15 | null | null |
| UserA | Log in | 02/08/2019 10:50:34 | Log Out | 02/08/2019 10:57:21 |

The query I tried already is below:

```
select * from 
(
select  "User Name" , "Event" , "Date" , "IP Address" 
from log_activities log_in 
where "Event" = 'User Logged In'
)log_in
left join 
(
select  "User Name" , "Event" , "Date" , "IP Address" 
from log_activities log_out 
where "Event" = 'User Logged Out'
)log_out
on
log_in."User Name" = log_out."User Name" 
and TO_DATE(log_in."Date" ,'DD/MM/YYYY') = TO_DATE(log_out."Date" ,'DD/MM/YYYY')
and log_in."Date"  < log_out."Date" 
and log_in."IP Address" = log_out."IP Address"
```

Comment: You haven't really asked a question - what is the current output you have, and what do you need help with?

Comment: i need a query that helps me achieve the second table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I view this as "I want all log in events.  Then I want the next log out if that is the next event".  If so, `lead()` seems like the most useful approach:

```
select la.username, la.event as login_event, la.date as login_date,
       la.next_event as logout_event, la.next_date as logout_date
from (select la.*
             lead(event) over (partition by username order by date) as next_event,
             lead(date) over (partition by username order by date) as next_date
      from log_activities la
     ) la
where event = 'Log in';
```

Comment: thanks! this worked! chose this as correct answer since its the first one i tried

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lead` analytical function and `CASE..WHEN` as follows:

```
select t.username, 
       t.event as login_event, 
       t.date as login_date,
       case when t.lead_event = 'Log Out' then t.lead_event end as logout_event, 
       case when t.lead_event = 'Log Out' then t.lead_date end as logout_date
from (select t.*,
             lead(event) over (partition by username order by date) as lead_event,
             lead(date) over (partition by username order by date) as lead_date
      from log_activities t
     ) t
where t.event = 'Log in';
```

Answer (score 0):

This reads like a gaps-and-island problem. I would recommend a window count of logins to build the groups, then aggregation:

```
select username, 
    'Log in' as log_in_event,
    min(date) as log_in_date,
    max(event) filter(where event = 'Log Out') as log_out_event,
    max(date)  filter(where event = 'Log Out') as log_out_date
from (
    select la.*,
        count(*) 
            filter(where event = 'Log in') 
            over(partition by username order by date) as grp
    from log_activities la
) la
group by username, grp
```